# Реализация вложенных классов вне родителя

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

При создании классов в приложении появилась необходимость разделить класс на несколько файлов из-за его размера.
Вопрос состоит в том, можно ли реализовать классы, вложенные в родитель?

Например в основном файле есть класс:

```py
class Test:
    class TestInner1:
        pass
    class TestInner2:
        pass
    class TestInner3:
        pass
```

Я могу разделить это на файлы:

```py
# --- Main file ---
from inner1 import TestInner1
from inner2 import TestInner2
from inner3 import TestInner3

class Test:
   class TestInner1(TestInner1):
      pass
   class TestInner2(TestInner2):
      pass
   class TestInner3(TestInner3):
      pass

# --- inner1 ---
class TestInner1:
    # code

# --- inner2 ---
class TestInner2:
    # code

# --- inner3 ---
class TestInner3:
    # code
```

Но в таком случае в главном классе я реализую классы, дочерние тем, что лежат в другом файле.

Возможно ли сделать это без такого костыля?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, зачем вообще делать в таком случае классы внутри другого класса. Это не несёт никакой практической пользы и так делают в основном, если есть маленький компактный класс и он всё равно понадобится только внутри большого класса, так что можно просто объявить его там и не загромождать глобальную область видимости.

Но если очень уж хочется чтобы они были именно внутри, то, кажется должно сработать что-то подобное:

```
import inner1
import inner2
import inner3

class Test:
   TestInner1 = inner1.TestInner1
   TestInner2 = inner2.TestInner2
   TestInner3 = inner3.TestInner3
```